# How can I create a Sublime Package from a Snippet Collection?

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I have a collection of [Sublime Snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html). I want to make them easier to install / accessible for others via [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/).

I found [this link](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#package-contents), but it is not very helpful. Most helpful would be a minimal package which does it, with instructions how to upload

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this small package](https://github.com/je-poy/extjs-sublime-snippets) it seems that there is no directory structure / package description file. It's simply flat all files in one directory.

Once this is done, there is also a [guide how to upload to package control](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package).